# how to create mysql database using servlet please give some basic ideas

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am working on my last year project. I want to connect `MySQL` database using  `JDBC`,
Please any one give me basic idea regarding that how to create `MySQL` database using `servlet`

Answer (score 1):

Create Static variables likebelow in your class

```
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "username";
   static final String PASS = "password";
```

And then call  createDb method based on your  `doGet` or `doPost`

```
         public static void CreateDb() {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating database...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();

      String sql = "CREATE DATABASE STUDENTS";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
      System.out.println("Database created successfully...");
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end JDBCExample
```

Answer (score 0):

Servlet

```
doXXX(){

//Obtain DriverManager instance
//Create a connection with `connecturl`
//Create Statement to interact with db
//Have Resultset with data


}
```

Comment: depends on which method your html form calls `method=POST` or `method=GET` in your html ??